# Sun Fire X4200 (not M2) Firmware (BIOS/ILOM)?

Tags: oracle, sun

i've running BIOS/ILOM 1.0 and it sucks with the hyperthreading sync error flood :(

I just got my hands on a nice Sun Fire x64 server but I'm in a bit of a bind.  I need BIOS and ILOM files for a Sun Fire x4200 (not M2) but can't find them anywhere.

This server hasn't been updated, ever.  The BIOS and ILOM are version 1.0 and I'd really like to get them patched up to fix problems I'm having with Sun's terrible Java-based ILOM system.

… oracle service contract is not available ...

My searches have turned up nothing on the usual suspects (torrent trackers, file share sites, etc.) and I'm doubtful that my polite email to Oracle Support will get me anywhere.

I know it's a long shot, but does anyone have these kinds of files archived, or know of a mirror that hosts them?

hyperthreading sync error flood:
- solaris 10 works
- windows 2012 sometime crash at boot
- debian amd64 crash at boot

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find the documentation for the SF X4200 on the [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19121-01/sf.x4200/index.html) website. The [firmware](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/patches/firmware/release-history-jsp-138416.html) is there too , specifically [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/patches/firmware/release-history-jsp-138416.html#X4100) but you'll need to be able to log in to the oracle website to download it.

Comment: oracle service contract is not available :/